# How can i rename the file on google Colab

Tags: shared-libraries, google-colaboratory

i want rename file by python via OS library, i want rename "/content/Wav2Lip/results/result_voice.mp4" to "/content/Wav2Lip/results/result_voiceTest.mp4", but seem the OS library can't install Google colab, anyone can help me.are there any ideal?

[i want to rename mp4 file via Google colab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/59GNf.png)

[google colab cant install os library](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZPLLZ.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import os

old_name = r"/content/EXP.csv"
new_name = r"/content/EXP_NEW.csv"
os.rename(old_name, new_name)
```

NOTE: `Don't go for

```
! pip install os
```

just use above piece of code it works

Try it once

Apart from that i use google colab as develpment environment and use python(ver:3.7.13).

NOTE: sometime changes not reflect so please refresh google colab once.

*********************GENERAL METHOD**********************

1. open google colab
2. go to file
3. click on file name that you want to rename
4. once you click on file name you see three vertical dot in the right side of file name
5. click on three verticle dot and you see rename file
6. click on rename file and change the file name.